# How to get an array of property names from base class in an inheritance context with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, reflection

Here I have a bunch of entity classes composed like this:

```
<?php
class BaseModel {
    protected $Id;
    protected $CreateDate;
    protected $LastUpdateDate;
    // public setters, getters and validation methods
    public function getClassFields(){
        // how to get an array containing all property names,
        // including those from inherited classes?
        $array = (array) $this; //this do not work =(
        return $array;
    }
}

class FooModel extends BaseModel {
    protected $Bar;
    protected $Baz;
    protected $Loo;
    // public setters, getters and validation methods
}
?>
```

I want to get an array containing `["Id", "CreateDate", "LastUpdateDate", "Bar", "Baz", "Loo"]`. How do I accomplish this?

**What I've tried:**

When I try to do an array cast `$array = (array) new FooModel()` from outside of the class or `$array = (array) $this` from inside of base class, both do not work... I think that `get_object_vars` function don't work since all properties are protected.

Should I use reflection instead?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your current method works, except the keys are preceded with ` * ` like `[ * Bar] =>
[ * Baz] =>
[ * Loo] =>
[ * Id] =>
[ * CreateDate] =>
[ * LastUpdateDate] =>`

Comment: Have you tried something with [get_class_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thank you for your comment. When I iterate over resulting array, something like this `foreach ($array as $k => $v)`, the keys (`$k`) are empty... I don't know where I'm wrong...

Comment: @FirstOne Thank you for your comment. I'll check this out! o/

Comment: @FirstOne Could you post this as an answer? I resolved this using `return array_keys(get_class_vars(get_class($this)));` at `getClassFields()` method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to get the variables from within the class, you could use a built-in function: `get_class_vars`.

---

So here is something more elaborate...

Replace your code with this:

```
class BaseModel {
    protected $Id;
    protected $CreateDate;
    protected $LastUpdateDate;
    // public setters, getters and validation methods
    public function getClassFields(){
        return array_keys(get_class_vars(get_class($this))); // changed
    }
}

class FooModel extends BaseModel {
    protected $Bar;
    protected $Baz;
    protected $Loo;
    // public setters, getters and validation methods
}
```

And then, if you use:

```
$foo = new BaseModel();
print_r($foo->getClassFields());
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Id [1] => CreateDate [2] => LastUpdateDate )
```

If you use it on the child:

```
$bar = new FooModel();
print_r($bar->getClassFields());
```

The output is now:

```
Array ( [0] => Bar [1] => Baz [2] => Loo [3] => Id [4] => CreateDate [5] => LastUpdateDate )
```

---

**References:**

[**get_class**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php): *Returns the name of the class of an object* 
[**get_class_vars**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php): *Get the default properties of the class* 
[**array_keys**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php): Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

---

**Sidenote:** if you don't want your `BaseModel` class to be instantiated, change it to abstract:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('FooModel');
$properties = $ref->getProperties();
$result = array();
foreach($properties as $i=>$prop){ 
  $result[] = $prop->getName();
}
```

The $result array will hold the properties you want.